# jquery wizard form step

Tags: jquery

hola comunidad tengo un pequeño problema estoy tratando de hacer un **step form** personalisado sin ninguna libreria y para ello stoy usando animate y algunos efectos ...

en el **html** tengo estos 3 **fieldeset** con algunos inputs a llenar y dentro tienen un boton next que al clikear me pasara al siguiente **fieldeset** mediante una animacion con jquery, y el ultimo tiene un boton finish entonces estoy haciendo lo siguiente...

```
<fieldset>
   <!-- some inputs-->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <!-- some inputs-->
   <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
     <!-- some inputs-->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Finish" />
</fieldset>
```

**js file**

en el js estoy capturando el elemento padre de los next buton con `parent()` para lograr el efecto que quiero al hacer la animation pero me lanza el siguiente error

> TypeError: current_fs.animate is not a function[Learn More]
>   wizard.html:230:2

```
    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {//here is the error
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

esete codigo es un poco largo pero solo estoy publicando la parte del error 
alguna idea de que estoy hacinedo mal? gracias

Comment: Que version de jQuery y jQueryUI estas usando?

Comment: @alanfcm 3.3.1.slim.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando la version `slim` de jQuery que no incluye la libreria completa.  Debes usar la libreria completa `jquery.min.js`

```js
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {//here is the error
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
   <!-- some inputs-->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <!-- some inputs-->
   <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
     <!-- some inputs-->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Finish" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: genial gracias estaba estancado no sabia lo de la libreria saludos amigo me salvaste horas de trabajo!!